# iOS, iPad - NavigationBar appears on rotating device

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

I have an issue with the navigation bar.
I have screen with NavBar and opened half transparent view on full screen (it covers NavBar).
Then, if I change device orientation by 180 degree (my app only, for landscape), then NavBar appears on top while animation. NavBar goes back under transparent view after animation completes.
Does somebody face the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

How are you presenting the transparent view? If you are presenting it modally or using a UIPopover, both of these will be removed from the window during the rotation and then added back afterwards.

Have you perhaps tried adding the view as a subview of the window, above the navigation bar, like such?

```
    [self.view.window insertSubview:your_view aboveSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

Comment: Yes. i'm using code like this: `[self.navigationController.view addSubview:MyTransparetView]`